# Make SWF extension run with Internet Explorer

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set extension swf to internet explorer on many computers. When I run this script it says .swf=InternetExplorer but it never changes in the gui and it does not work. Why is this not failing and how can i get it to work? Also Im on a domain I dont know why I need To enable PSRemoting to make it work?

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force

$comps="it-tech"; 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comps { cmd /c assoc .swf=InternetExplorer.Application }
```

It returns completed ... but does not actually change anything...

Comment: Did you restart explorer.exe on the `it-tech` computer after changing the setting?  The easiest way to do this is to log out and back in (or just reboot)

Comment: yes i did and nothing changed even in the gui